# React-Table: Type is invalid, expected string (with correct import/export)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

React-Table is not rendering when given valid ‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`data` and `columns` props.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Previous questions were almost all resolved by fixing the named vs. default import/export methods between the files, but I've verified that and now resorted to distilling things into the same JSX file while still getting the same error.

**Format of my mapped columns.**
[image]

**Format of my data.**
[image]

**My app JSX**, where I try to render a ReactTable with the DataTable and mapped columns.
  [image: app.jsx]

**My index CSHTML file**, where I set a JS variable to the DataTable model.
  [image: Index.cshtml]

Comment: can you post your code in plain text rather than screenshots? this helps with search discoverability (and imgur is blocked in my work network here).

Comment: You have an accessor as `Job #`? So you have a data key in your response objects that is `Job #`? (with a space and a special character?)